# JQuery UI problems on Draggable and Resizable images

Tags: javascript, image, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-resizable

I'm having real headaches trying to work out a problem I have at the moment on a web page, I hope you can give me a hand :D.
I have dive for a related topic but I've not found any one with the same problem, using several images.

What I want to achieve:
"I want to include draggable and resizable images in a div". The images one by on are added when a link is clicked.

I have mainly 3 problems(also explained with images):

- When I add a new item and it's marked as resizable, it appears below the last image, instead of beside. (When it's nor marked as resizable it appears beside)
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dBXF.jpg
- When I drag an image, changing his Y axis, and then try to resize it, it's automatically moved to the las Y axis position (X is consistent).
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/rF9KK.jpg
- When I drag an image, and after I try to resize the other one, the Y position of the dragged image changes.
  h**p://i.stack.imgur.com/OMWEr.jpg

I don't know what to do, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried an attempt to recreate what you wanted to achieve and arrived at this [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/drewP/suWa7/1/)
I hope it helps in some way.
Here is my resolution to the problems you are encountering:
**Problem 1:**

I achieved the separation of the resizable and the non-resizable images by by assigning them into separate divs. (seems easier that way :P). 

**Problem 2 & Problem 3:** 
I was not able to encounter this two problems, are you using **alsoResize** or **grid**
options?

***[Updated Post]***

I saw the problem you were encountering and modified my initial code, here is the [result](http://jsfiddle.net/drewP/suWa7/5/).

 I provided comments on the lines that I updated.

the resizing problem you were encountering is because the img element is not absolutely positioned in the page.

I hope that this helps you in some way :)

Comment: Problem 1 and 2 solved!!! thanks so much, I'd tried too to use a div wrapper, but I forgot to set: "display: inline-block;" thanks so much, really.

Comment: About problem 3, there are also at the sample you provided, when you set 2 images resizables and draggables, if you resize(increase de height) of the 1st image, then drag the second one to the top of the div and resize again the first image(decreasing height) the 2nd image goes up.